# Error: Call to undefined function drush_invoke_process()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

When attempting to run a drush command from drupal code using the drush_invoke_process() command, I receive the error in the title of this question. I am running Drupal 7.61 and, from what I can see, the function should be included with the drupal installation. http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes%21command.inc/function/drush_invoke_process/7.x

Is there a common reason this function may not be included or could it have been blocked/overridden by another module?

If you can't tell I am somewhat new to Drupal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note, I have run drush commands with the shell_exec() function. However, the commands did not seem to consistently execute.

Comment: It appears that any drush_* function does not work. Is there a module I need to include?